# Unable to connect Visual Studio to remotebuild on El Capitan VM

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have a Cordova-Ionic application on Visual Studio (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015, Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2). I am able to run the app on my android phone and all is good. I want to test the app by also running it on an iPhone/iOS simulator.

I have OS X El Capitan (version 10.11.6) running as a VM on virtual box. I have been following this guide (https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/) to try to test the app on apple devices. I have installed version 0.12.9 Node.js and Xcode Version 8 Beta 4. I have also installed xcode command line tools, remote agent, homebrew. I have tried running 'remotebuild  test' in a terminal and it executes successfully, ending with 'taco-remote test passed.' However, this is where the problems start.

To attempt to use secure remotebuild, i run 'remotebuild certificates reset' and then 'remotebuild certificates generate' in the terminal. I see
host: noyolks-iMac.local
port: 3000
PIN: 121422
I then run **'remotebuild'**. On visual studios on my windows machine, I then go to tools -> options -> tools for apache cordova -> iOS configuration. I set 'Enable remote iOS processing' to 'true', **'host' to 'noyolks-iMac.local'**, 'port' to '3000', 'secure mode' to 'true', 'security pin' to '121422'. However, when i press ok, i see the following error popup **'Unable to connect to remote iOS build server. Underlying exception: The remote name could not be resolved: 'noyolks-imac.local''**.

I try using the IP instead in place of the host name as suggested in the guide. On OS X, i go system preferences -> network. I then see '10.0.2.15' under IP address. I go back to my windows machine. I try **'10.0.2.15' in place of the 'host'**. When i press ok, i see the following error popup **'An error occurred trying to acquire certificate from https://10.0.2.15.'**.

Please note, I ensured that all the above was done within the 10 minutes window before the security pin expires.

Following the guide, I then tried to start the remote agent without secure mode. I run **'remotebuild --secure false'**. Once again on visual studio on my windows machine, i try **host 'noyolks-imac.local'** first (with 'port' to '3000', 'enable remote iOS processing' to 'true', 'secure mode' to 'false') and i get the error popup **'Unable to connect to remote iOS build server. Underlying exception: The remote name could not be resolved: 'noyolks-imac.local''**.

Once again, running without secure mode, i instead use the ip address in place of the **host '10.0.2.15'**. I get the error popup **'Unable to connect to remote iOS build server. Underlying exception: Unable to connect to the remote server'**.

I have also tried a similar procedure using a friends mac book pro and have not been able to get this to work. Any help would be appreciated and please do feel free to ask for any other information you might need.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try turn off the firewall, and try ping your mac with the IP address?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I fixed it by changing the network adapter to the 'bridged adapter' after failing to ping my mac VM with the IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot. The problem was that I couldnt even ping my El Capitan VM. Changing the network adapter settings in virtualbox to 'bridged adapter' solved this.